# Django - Pass attribute via URL from utils.py to template

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I am failing on passing an attribute from utils.py to a template

- pass the attribute as URL and read that in a template (via URL as I don't know better)

utils.py is creating a monthly calendar table and a loop goes through every day of the month checking how many slots per room are available for reservation each day (this part is fine) . I am trying to pass the *day* to a daily schedule template. This part is only running if I **don't** add an attribute. Just link everyday to the same template.

```
utils.py 

# check available slots per room for that day / return room_name and free_slots

for rooms in rooms_list:
    
        slot_calculation = 5 - Room.objects.filter(event__room = rooms, event__start_time__day=day).count()
        d += f'<br>{rooms.get_roomlist} {slot_calculation}</li>'

# create a hyperlink for each day cell to template calendar_rooms
url = reverse("cal:calendar_rooms") <--- #how do I pass the attribute right here?
return f'<td><span class="date"><a href="{url}">{day}</a></span><ul> {d} </ul></td>'
```

Calling template is running as long as I don't add < attr > in urls.py

```
urls.py
url(r'^calendar_rooms/<attr>/$', views.cal_rooms, name='calendar_rooms'),
```

View.py should accept input like http://localhost:800/calendar_rooms/20200101/ but all I get is a *404 - Using the URLconf defined in hot_django.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:*
I have tried a HttpResponse as well.

```
view.py 
# how do I pass an attribute?

def cal_rooms(request, attr):    
context = {
    'attr': attr,
}
return render(request, 'cal/calendar_rooms.html', context)
```

I have tried all kinds of solutions to no avail. I not sure if passing the attr via URL is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

self answer:
just switched *url* in urls.py to *path* and it is running now.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
I was using a deprecated code